# Seeking land use/ land cover map, population density map for states of Gujarat and Maharashtra (in India)?

Tags: data, land-cover, population, india, land-use

I need to find land use /land cover and population density layers for the states of Gujarat and Maharashtra in India.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  This is a question that I think may be more suited to researching/asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

With a quick search, I found the following links, but I am not sure they will help you or not:

Population: [India / National Statistics / 2015](http://global.census.okfn.org/entry/in/statistics)

Land use/cover: [The Global Land Cover Map](http://www.iscgm.org/gm/glcnmo.html)